# How to fade out sides of images?

Tags: css

When you make the browser wider, you will notice that the right and left side of the images is fading out in black.

I need to apply the same feature to my gallery but have no idea. I have found this >> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437400/css-fade-out-horizontal-rule-line-styled-div-effect-without-images) as well but it's just a horizontal line not sure how to attach it to both sides of images and make the same result as the link.

In the comments, ultranaut mentioned that I could apply the filter on images. Still, the question is if I use it on the images how to adjust the size, because browser windows might be in different sizes and the pictures side should be adjustable to every browser size.

Comment: fwiw, the effect on the airbnb hero unit is in the images themselves, not css, look at e.g. https://a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/landing_pages/home_v2/hero/6400-f76e410d0fc03ab3dc089ceb8a151069.jpg

Comment: @ultranaut, yeah but I am wondering how to apply it using CSS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one way to skin this cat:

HTML:

```
<div class="frame">
  <div class="fade"></div>
  <img src="picture.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.frame {
    width: 315px;
    height: 165px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.fade {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, 
                rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%, 
                rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
                rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
                rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%
    );
}
```

Personally, I'm not a huge fan of the (semantically) unnecessary `fade` div, and I'm sure there's probably a more clever way to do the same effect without it, but it'll work.

I only included the webkit prefixed rule, if you want to get legit you'd need to add the other vendor prefixes.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/M9UtU/).

**Update**:
If the image is just serving as background—as is the case in your linked example—the gradient and image can both be set on the css for the containing element:

```
.frame {
  width: 315px;
  height: 165px;
  margin: 20px;

  background-image: url(picture.jpg);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, 
    rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
    rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
    rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%
  ),
  url(picture.jpg);
}

...

<div class="frame">
  Content...
</div>
```

Less muss, less fuss: [new-style fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/Mx3dx/) with vendor prefixes and everything.

Comment: great thanks, but how to change in a way to be exactly the same as sample website in the question? I've tried to change it but to no avail. I need it to be exactly the same as the sample with black color and the percentage of fading.

Comment: that's what `color-stops` do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient#Gradient_with_multiple_color_stops

Comment: I just added your css to my :after pseudo element. Works wonderfully on modern browsers

Answer (score 2):

Using just CSS3, try a [Vignette](http://nimbupani.com/vignettes-with-css3-box-shadows.html).

Verbatim code:

HTML:

```
<p class="vignette"><img src="image.jpg"></p>
```

CSS:

```
p.vignette {
  position: relative;
}
p.vignette img {
 display: block;
}
p.vignette:after {
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10em #666;  
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10em #666;   
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 10em #666;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 2;
 content: "";
}
```

Comment: @DanielMorgan your link is dead